# Mutliple business hours in full calendar with two shifts each day

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have integrated full calendar into my website. One of my requirement is to have business hours fetch from database and render it on the calendar. So basically each day has two shifts(Morning and evening). I need to be able to create an array of business hours with the values getting populated from database. Out of the box, I'm able to use the below code to render a common business hours.

```
businessHours:
  {
    start: '10:00:00',
    end: '16:00:00',
    dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
  },
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
businessHours:[
{
  start: '10:00:00',
  end: '13:00:00',
  dow: [0]
},
{
  start: '14:00:00',
  end: '19:00:00',
  dow: [0]
},
{
  start: '09:00:00',
  end: '12:00:00',
  dow: [1]
},
{
  start: '12:30:00',
  end: '18:00:00',
  dow: [1]
},
]
```

If this is not possible with the existing properties of full calendar, is there any other to achieve this ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also needed the same feature. I forked the repo to

https://github.com/dtmonterrey/fullcalendar

and implemented a solution that works for me. It works with a single businessHours definition or with an array of businessHours definitions (like the example you tried).

Example:

```
    businessHours:[ 
        {
            start: '09:00',
            end: '13:00',
            dow: [1, 2]
        },
        {
            start: '14:00',
            end: '16:00',
            dow: [1, 2]
        },
        {
            start: '10:00',
            end: '19:00',
            dow: [4]
        },
        {
            start: '06:00',
            end: '10:30',
            dow: [6]
        },
        {
            start: '13:00',
            end: '17:00',
            dow: [6]
        },
        {
            start: '20:00',
            end: '23:00',
            dow: [6]
        }
    ]
```

I have created a pull request. Suggestions are welcome.

**example and demo**

I couldn't get jsfiddle to work, so the demo for

http://jsfiddle.net/t7aczbdt/

is here

http://eo14.com/static/fullcalendar/

You could try it on your computer: uncompress this http://eo14.com/static/fullcalendar.zip and open with your browser.

Comment: Any sample jsfiddle should be really helpful :D

Comment: @user1744973 Added example and demo. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you it saved my hours, simple soloution

Comment: how can use it with latest version?

Comment: I'll have a look and I'll have an answer in about an hour

Comment: This is the bug report that originated this fork https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2686 When I forked the repo to solve my problem I also created a pull request to incorporate this solution on the original repo https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/pull/237

Comment: @KashifR I have updated the repo with the new version 2.5.0

Comment: @Evandro P. Alves Bundle of thanks, i will check and let you know..Thanks again(Up vote)

Comment: This helped a lot! Thanks for that, I'm using it for business hours and also for already booked slots (was having issues using Background Events and disabling click on it).

Comment: Hi, may i know how did u disable the click event for the non business hours (in your demo)? i'm able to add events for non business hours in my app, i'm using 3.3v please someone help me, how to disable click event for non business hours?

Comment: I found the answer used the selectConstraint and eventConstraint options to prevent click event in non business hours (from full calendar 2.2version). https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectConstraint/ https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventConstraint/ Thanks :)

Comment: I want to have different businesshours in odd and even weeknumbers. Any help is appreciated! TIA.

Answer (score 1):

We can add *each* of our `business hours` as `events` with the following `options` - this is the standard options that `fullcalendar` works with to populate the `businessHours` option:-

```
{
  ...
  events: [
    // business hours 1
    {
        className: 'fc-nonbusiness',
        start: '09:00',
        end: '17:00',
        dow: [1, 2, 3, 4], // monday - thursday
        rendering: 'inverse-background'
    },
    // business hours 2
    {
        className: 'fc-nonbusiness',
        start: '10:00',
        end: '15:00',
        dow: [6], // saturday
        rendering: 'inverse-background'
    }],
 ...
}
```

**Note** the magic is done by `className : fc-nonbusiness` which is counter-intutive; however, that is reversed by the option `rendering:'inverse-background` and all works well.

Good Luck.

Comment: Since v4 the attribute names changed a little, but the principal still works. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours I had to define additional the background color for `.fc .fc-bg-event.fc-non-business`.